# While loop repeating in coin flip function

Tags: python, while-loop

I dont understand why the following while loop wont end? The following code just keeps endlessly asking for the user input. It should be a simple function that flips a coin and then returns whether the user guess correctly or not.. as far as I can tell the boolean expressions in the while statement are ok.

Appreciate any feedback and sorry id advance if the format isnt correct..

```py
import random

def coin_flip():

    random_choice = random.randint(1,2)

    user_input = ""

    if random_choice == 1:

        random_choice = "Heads"

    else:

        random_choice = "Tails"

    while user_input != "Heads" or user_input != "Tails":

        user_input = input("Heads or Tails?")

    if user_input == random_choice:

        print("Congratulations!", "The result was", random_choice, " and you guess correctly!")

    else:

        print("Bad luck!", "The result was", random_choice, " and you guessed incorrectly.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your condition is correct however you need to indent correctly. I am assuming it should loop continuously until the user guesses the right answer break. Check the code below

```
import random

def coin_flip():

    random_choice = random.randint(1,2)
    if random_choice == 1:
        random_choice = "Heads"
    else:
        random_choice = "Tails"


    user_input = ""
    while True:
        user_input = input("Heads or Tails?")
        if user_input == random_choice:
            print("Congratulations!", "The result was", random_choice, " and you guess correctly!")
            break;
        else:
            print("Bad luck!", "The result was", random_choice, " and you guessed incorrectly.")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

My idea was actually to loop while the user gave invalid answers, for ex, if the user misspelss "Heads" or "Tails, so it would continue asking the user for the valid inputs until they were correctly entered.

Not sure I understood the while loop in your suggestion, so while user input is not Heads or Tails it will assign the the random_choice variables?

Comment: I fixed it what I am doing is while true keep getting input from the user until he gets it right. You can change the value of your coin by adding the random variable  inside the loop

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thank you! Yes..that makes more sense and is also a more elegant solution to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `or` condition:

> while user_input != "Heads" or user_input != "Tails":

The user input may be "Heads", in which case `user_input != "Tails"`. It may instead be "Tails", in which case `user_input != "Heads"`.

You could simply use an `and`, but the most Pythonic way to approach this would be:

> while user_input not in ("Heads", "Tails"):

Hope that helps.